# Infinite scrolling from xml

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

**Dear Sirs,
I am loading an xml file with over 1000 records and the scheme of it is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<deals>

<deal>
<deal_id>1</deal_id>
<deal_title> <![CDATA[THE TITLE]]> </deal_title>
<deal_description> <![CDATA[THE DESCRIPTION]]> </deal_description>
<deal_url> <![CDATA[http://www.thedomain.com]]> </deal_url>
<deal_price>12.00</deal_price>
<deal_previous_price>68.00</deal_previous_price>
<deal_discount>82</deal_discount>
<deal_image> <![CDATA[http://www.thedomain.com/images/image.jpg]]> </deal_image>
<deal_shop>DEAL SITE NAME</deal_shop>
</deal>

</deals>
```

**Unfortunately someone provides me this xml and  has no ordering.
Now i am using the code below to load my xml inside my php file 4 records from the xml:**

```
<ol class="timeline" id="updates">

<?php

$url = "http://www.somedomain.com/xml.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$bar_count = $xml->deal->count();


$limit = 0;
$num = 4;
foreach($xml->deal as $deal)
{

if($limit == $num)
break;



echo'
<li>
<div class="dealmasterblock" id="'.$num.'">
<div class="dealsite">'.$deal->deal_shop.'</div>
<div class="dealsimageblock">
<div class="pricebg">
<div style="width:55px; height:26px; float:left; margin-left:8px; margin-top:14px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#333; font-size:18px;">-'.$deal->deal_discount.'%</div>
</div>
<div class="dealsimg"><img src="'.$deal->deal_image.'" width="284" height="199" border="0" /></div></div>
<div class="others">
<div class="dealtitle">'.$deal->deal_title.'</div>
</div>
<div class="moreoptions">
<div style="width:465px; height:34px; float:left; margin-top:3px;">
<div style="width:180px; height:28px; padding-top:6px; float:left; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; background-color:#3189EE; color:#FFF; text-align:center; border-right:1px solid #0CF; margin-right:10px;">Αρχική τιμή: '.$deal->deal_previous_price.'€</div>
<div style="width:180px; height:28px; padding-top:6px; float:left; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; background-color:#3189EE; color:#FFF; text-align:center; border-right:1px solid #0CF;">Μόνο: '.$deal->deal_price.'€</div>
</div>
<div style="width:147px; height:40px; float:right;"><a href="'.$deal->deal_url.'" target="_blank"><img src="images/morebtn.png" width="147" height="40" border="0" /></a></div>
</div>
</div>
</li>'; 

$limit++;
}

?>
</ol>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="more<?php echo $num; ?>" class="morebox">
<a href="#" class="more" id="<?php echo $num; ?>">περισσότερα...</a>
</div>


<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

**I have attached a jquery / ajax code to the button with class more so when i pressing it it will be load more records.
The jquery code is:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.more').on('click', function(evt){

var ID = $(this).attr("id");

if(ID)
{

$("#more"+ID).html('<img src="images/moreajax.gif" />');

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "moredeals.php",
data: "lastmsg="+ ID, 
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("ol#updates").append(html);
$("#more"+ID).remove();
//$('ol#updates').fadeIn("slow");
//alert('Return ok');
//$("#more"+ID).html('<img src="images/moreajax.gif" />');
}

});
}
else
{
$(".morebox").html('The End');

}
return false;
});

});
</script>
```

Moredeals.php that it is the ajax file to load more deals is:

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.somedomain.com/xml.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

if(isSet($_POST['lastmsg']))
{

$lastmsg=$_POST['lastmsg'];

$url = "http://www.clickbanner.gr/xml/?xml_type=deals&affiliate_ID=16022";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$bar_count = $xml->deal->count();


$limit = 0;
$num = 8;
foreach($xml->deal as $deal)
{

if($limit == $num)
break;



echo'
<li>
<div class="dealmasterblock" id="'.$num.'">
<div class="dealsite">'.$deal->deal_shop.'</div>
<div class="dealsimageblock">
<div class="pricebg">
<div style="width:55px; height:26px; float:left; margin-left:8px; margin-top:14px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#333; font-size:18px;">-'.$deal->deal_discount.'%</div>
</div>
<div class="dealsimg"><img src="'.$deal->deal_image.'" width="284" height="199" border="0" /></div></div>
<div class="others">
<div class="dealtitle">'.$deal->deal_title.'</div>
</div>
<div class="moreoptions">
<div style="width:465px; height:34px; float:left; margin-top:3px;">
<div style="width:180px; height:28px; padding-top:6px; float:left; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; background-color:#3189EE; color:#FFF; text-align:center; border-right:1px solid #0CF; margin-right:10px;">Αρχική τιμή: '.$deal->deal_previous_price.'€</div>
<div style="width:180px; height:28px; padding-top:6px; float:left; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; background-color:#3189EE; color:#FFF; text-align:center; border-right:1px solid #0CF;">Μόνο: '.$deal->deal_price.'€</div>
</div>
<div style="width:147px; height:40px; float:right;"><a href="'.$deal->deal_url.'" target="_blank"><img src="images/morebtn.png" width="147" height="40" border="0" /></a></div>
</div>
</div>
</li>'; 



$limit++;
}
?>


<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="more<?php echo $num; ?>" class="morebox">
<a href="#" class="more" id="<?php echo $num; ?>">περισσότερα...</a>
</div>

<?php
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.more').on('click', function(evt){

var ID = $(this).attr("id");

if(ID)
{

$("#more"+ID).html('<img src="images/moreajax.gif" />');

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "moredeals.php",
data: "lastmsg="+ ID, 
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("ol#updates").append(html);
$("#more"+ID).remove();
}

});
}
else
{
$(".morebox").html('The End');
}
return false;

});

});
</script>
```

Now the problem is that when more button is pressed i can load more 8 deals but is the same with 4 first records.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @GOD That really depends on the use case.

Comment: `Now the problem is that when more button is pressed i can load more 8 deals but is the same with 4 first records.` - Can I ask, what if you press the button 3-4-5 times, what then? Are you getting the 4 records over and over again?

Comment: @metal_fan yes i am getting the 4 same records because i cant set a unique id for each <deal> so in the ajax file grab the last id and load somehow the rest 4 records or more...

Comment: i think that if we can solve it will be a very good example tutorial for deal aggregator sites

Comment: you can check my example here: http://www.thecrawler.gr/deals

Comment: OK, I got it. All what you're trying to do is called **AJAX-pagination**. And it's not infinity scrolling, it's a fail to increment a value on each page click. And why you can't set a unique id for each deal? Why not a tag at least, like `<deal id="1">....</deal>`

Comment: @metal_fan because as i mentioned i am grabbing the xml file remotely. i can edit it <deal_id> is not 1, 2, 3, etc but 1700, 1640, 1500, etc...